# error while running struts 2 code

Tags: eclipse

I am getting a HTTP ERROR: 503 service unavailable error while running a sturts 2 application . the exact error is

HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /project_47/WEB-INF/classes/action/action_trial.java. Reason:

```
Service Unavailable
```

---

Powered by Jetty://

My console looks like this:

Starting preview server on port 8080

Modules:
  project_47 (/project_47)

2015-01-17 19:08:55.658:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
17 Jan, 2015 7:08:58 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
17 Jan, 2015 7:08:59 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
17 Jan, 2015 7:08:59 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.20.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.20.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:218)
    ... 22 more
2015-01-17 19:08:59.357:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED struts2: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.20.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.20.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
Caused by: 
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.20.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
Caused by: 
Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.20.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:218)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
2015-01-17 19:08:59.373:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/project_47,file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/},C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.20.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
Caused by: 
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.20.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
Caused by: 
Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/C:/project_47/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project_47/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.20.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:218)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
2015-01-17 19:08:59.544:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure that you have placed following necessary jar files in classpath.

```
antlr-2.7.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-lang3-3.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
struts2-core-2.3.20.jar
xstream-1.4.2.jar
xwork-core-2.3.20.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
```

2) Make sure your web.xml is correct, below is one sample

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Struts 2 Web Application</display-name>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

3)Make sure struts.xml is on classpath
.you can place it on default package
.Or you can place it on resources folder if you follow maven approach
.Or you can place it on the folder where manifest.mf is placed(usually it is src/conf/manifest.mf in case of netbeans ide)

4) Finally, if you are planning to use other jar files, include it also on the classpath.